# Authentication using the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow with the Microsoft Identity Platform (Azure AD) and @azure/msal-node in a Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I want to implement authentication using the [OAuth 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authorization code flow with the Microsoft Identity Platform (Azure AD) and the [@azure/msal-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node) library in a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) backend.

So I can call graph api on successful authentication.

I tried to adopt code from official example at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal%C2%A0)

Here is my code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { PublicClientApplication, LogLevel } = require('@azure/msal-node');

// Initialize the MSAL client with your authentication configuration
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}`,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
        console.log(message);
      },
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
      logLevel: LogLevel.Info
    }
  }
};

const msalClient = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

// Create an Express app
const app = express();

// Define a route for initiating the login process
app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const authCodeUrlParameters = {
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access', 'Calendars.Read'],
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
  };

  // Generate the authorization URL
  const authUrl = await msalClient.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters);
  console.log('alok', authUrl)

  // Redirect the user to the authorization URL
  res.redirect(authUrl);
});

// Define a route for handling the redirect callback
app.get('/redirect', async (req, res) => {
  const tokenRequest = {
    code: req.query.code,
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access', 'Calendars.Read'],
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
  };

  try {
    // Acquire an access token using the authorization code
    const response = await msalClient.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest);

    // use token now and save it for call graph api
    res.send('Authentication successful!');
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle the token acquisition error
    console.log(error);
    res.send('Authentication failed.');
  }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

After successful login I am getting the code via http://localhost:3000/redirect?code=something
But I am not able to get token in the line `await msalClient.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest)`
I am getting error

```
ServerError: invalid_client: 7000218 - [2023-05-19 12:26:56Z]: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
Trace ID: 1852de3e-3310-4503-a9c4-985e35880f00
Correlation ID: 22c042a3-0777-4151-a364-edad3312ccee
Timestamp: 2023-05-19 12:26:56Z - Correlation ID: 22c042a3-0777-4151-a364-edad3312ccee - Trace ID: 1852de3e-3310-4503-a9c4-985e35880f00
    at ServerError.AuthError [as constructor] (/home/alok/tmp/test-node/node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.cjs.js:498:24)
    at new ServerError (/home/alok/tmp/test-node/node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.cjs.js:3383:28)
    at ResponseHandler.validateTokenResponse (/home/alok/tmp/test-node/node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.cjs.js:5414:19)
    at AuthorizationCodeClient.<anonymous> (/home/alok/tmp/test-node/node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.cjs.js:5722:41)
    at step (/home/alok/tmp/test-node/node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.cjs.js:79:23)
    at Object.next (/home/alok/tmp/test-node/node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.cjs.js:60:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/alok/tmp/test-node/node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.cjs.js:50:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errorCode: 'invalid_client',
  errorMessage: "7000218 - [2023-05-19 12:26:56Z]: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.\r\n" +
    'Trace ID: 1852de3e-3310-4503-a9c4-985e35880f00\r\n' +
    'Correlation ID: 22c042a3-0777-4151-a364-edad3312ccee\r\n' +
    'Timestamp: 2023-05-19 12:26:56Z - Correlation ID: 22c042a3-0777-4151-a364-edad3312ccee - Trace ID: 1852de3e-3310-4503-a9c4-985e35880f00',
  subError: ''
}
```

I tried to get help from

1. [How do I resolve the error AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret' or 'client_assertion'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609432/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-aadsts7000218-the-request-body-must-contain-the-foll)
2. [AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68002063/aadsts7000218-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-client-as)
3. [The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534008/the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-client-assertion-or-cl)
4. [ROPC flow: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245406/ropc-flow-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-client-assert)

Out of these none are helpful for me.

What I am missing exactly so I am getting this error?

Comment: Sounds like your `tokenRequest` needs a client secret?

Comment: @juunas: I tried to pass client secret in `msalClient.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest)` but I got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, you need to enable `Allow public client flows` to **"Yes"** and add redirect URI by selecting platform as **Mobile and desktop applications** while using PublicClientApplication.

I cloned this [**Github sample**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/auth-code) and registered one Azure AD application by adding redirect URI in **`Web`** platform as below:

[image]

When I ran the sample and authenticated successfully, it asked for **consent** like below:

[image]

After accepting the above consent, I got **`code`** value in address bar and same error as you like this:

[image]

When I checked the code terminal, I got **similar logs** as you like below:

[image]

To resolve the error, I removed redirect URI from **`Web`** platform and added it in **`Mobile and desktop applications`**  platform by enabling Allow public client flows to **"Yes"**  like below:

**Redirect URI:**

[image]

**Enable public client flow:**

[image]

> Note that, there is no need to pass **client secret** in code if you make above changes while using PublicClientApplication.

When I ran the sample again after making above changes, I got below **response** like this:

[image]

**In Browser:**

[image]

In your case, check if you added redirect URI as **`Web`** and change it to **`Mobile and desktop applications`**  platform by enabling Allow public client flows to **"Yes"**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such an accurate and elaborate answer without knowing my application details :)

Comment: Can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/76525504/1762051