# AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Getting this error:
AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret
can anyone help me to solve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and share the code for sending the request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve the error AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client\_secret' or 'client\_assertion'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609432/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-aadsts70002-the-request-body-must-contain-the-follow)

Answer (score 1):

As your error message describes, your request body is missing the `client_secret` parameter.

[image]

Comment: where i can found my client_id and client_secret?

Comment: @mroma95  Log in to Azure portal>azure ad>App registrations>your app>Certificates & secrets https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlOVr.png

Comment: @mroma95  client id and tenant id :https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDVxm.png

Comment: okey so i need to create new app, but i have other problem because i'm writing the app to scan OneDrive i want to get files but to do it i need access token(all libraries i found need access token), It's possible to get access token from other side without register the new app? Ideally will be if user will get username and password and my app will start scan

Comment: @mroma95  I think you must register the application in Azure AD, otherwise you will not be able to obtain an access token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233873/discussion-between-mroma95-and-carl-zhao).