# How to grant admin-consent to an Enterprise application with Microsoft Authentication Library

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am tasked with granting admin-consent to an Enterprise application in a long list of tenants.

Currently I have automated this task with `JMeter` with the following steps:

1. `GET /{TenantId}/oauth2/authorize`
2. `POST /{TenantId}/login` (login with tenant admin account)
3. `POST /{TenantId}/Consent/Set`
4. `GET https://portal.azure.com/TokenAuthorize`

And the process is working OK. However I would like to change it to `MSAL` for two reasons: 1) JMeter is really not the best tool for this job, 2) I would also learn to use some of `MSAL`, which I believe will come in handy in the future.

However I am not able to even get a token using `MSAL`. Using the following readily available example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/blob/main/2.%20Client-Side%20Scenarios/Username-Password-Flow/src/main/java/UsernamePasswordFlow.java, the following exception appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
```

And I am not able to find the `client_secret` or the `client_assertion` for our Enterprise application.

Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please **note** that, **`client_secret`** or the **`client_assertion`** are sometimes required in ROPC flow based on the scenario as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request) like below:

[image]

***I created an Enterprise Application in my environment like below:***

[image]

**To resolve the error, try the below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> App Registrations -> Select App with your Enterprise Application name -> Authentication*

[image]

***If still the issue persists, create a client secret like below:***

*Go to Azure Portal -> App Registrations -> Select App with your Enterprise Application name -> Certificates & secrets*

[image]

**Reference:**

[How do I resolve the error AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret' or 'client_assertion' by Jayendran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609432/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-aadsts7000218-the-request-body-must-contain-the-foll)

Comment: hi RukminiMr-MT, thanks for your input but I am not able to locate my Enterprise application in the App registrations view. It does not appear in Owned applications nor in All applications

Comment: AFAIK, the Enterprise application must be displayed in the Enterprise application. Could you please include how did you create Enterprise application?

Comment: Verify whether you have selected this [**option**](https://i.imgur.com/wxv2Zxd.png) while creating Azure Enterprise Application.

Comment: I will ask for this information as I don't know how the application was created. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would just generate the correct link, as specified here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent

And click that several times.
Going through MSAL will not help you because it only does the user consent and not the admin consent.